# Control Headers in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I am trying to customize my server using Next.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({dev, dir: '../'})
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express()

    server.get('/a', (req, res) => {
      res.send("Palin text: Hello From Express server Riko :)")
    })

    server.get('/b', (req, res) => {
      return app.render(req, res, '/b', req.query)
    })

    server.get('/posts/:id', (req, res) => {
      return app.render(req, res, '/posts', { id: req.params.id })
    })

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.removeHeader('Transfer-Encoding')
      res.setHeader('Connection', 'close')
      return handle(req, res)
    })

    server.listen(port, err => {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
  })
```

When a page is being loaded i see that the response header `Connection` is set to 'keep-alive'. And this results in very long response time.

I tried to change the header here:

```
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.removeHeader('Transfer-Encoding')
  res.setHeader('Connection', 'close')
  return handle(req, res)
})
```

Without success though.

This is the Next.js configuration file:

```
module.exports = {
    distDir: 'build',
    poweredByHeader: false
}
```

Comment: Why would you like to change Connection to close? it will increase the loading time

Comment: I just want to have more control.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```js
res.set('Connection', 'close');
```